# Finite field extension over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I don't see why $[L:K]=4$, where

$L = \mathbb{F}_2(x,y) = \operatorname{Quot}(\mathbb{F}_2[x,y])$

and

$K = \mathbb{F}_2(x^2,y^2) = \operatorname{Quot}(\mathbb{F}_2[x^2,y^2])$

---

Let $p(X) = X^2-x^2 \in K[X]$. $p$ has leading coefficient $1$.

It is $p(X) = (X-x)(X+x)$ where $\pm x \notin K$.

Since $p$, with $\deg p \in \{2,3\}$ is reducible over $K$ iff $\exists a \in K: p(a) = 0$ -- and we already found two roots of $p$ which are not in $K$ -- it follows that $p(X)$ is irreducible over $K$ and therefore minimal polynomial of $x$.

It follows that $[K(x):K] = \deg p = 2$.

Now we show that $K(x) \neq L$ since $y \notin K(x)$ but $y \in L$: *How to do this?*

Now let $q(X) = X^2-y^2 \in K(x)[X]$, then $q$ again has leading coefficient $1$ and is irreducible (*show same way as above?*) and therefore minimal polynomial of $y$.

It follows that $[K(x,y):K]=[K(x,y):K(x)]\cdot[K(x):K]=\deg q \cdot \deg p=2 \cdot 2=4$.

Not we only need, that $K(x,y,) = L$ then it follows that $[L:K]=4$. *How to do this?*

Comment: +1 to you. For extra credit show that for all $z\in L\setminus K$, the minimal polynomial of $z$ is $$m_z(X)=X^2-z^2\in K[X].$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: analyze the tower of fields $L=K(x,y)\supseteq K(x)\supseteq K$. The polynomial $p(X)=X^2-x^2$ is an irreducible polynomial over $K$. The same is true for $q(X)=X-y^2$. Convince yourself that extending by one then the other results in $L$, and that this extension is degree $2\cdot 2$. (This basically amounts to showing that $y$ isn't in $K(x)$.)

$K$ for example is all polynomial fractions where the polynomials only have even powers of $x$ and $y$. $L$ is the same except you're allowed to have any powers of $x$ and $y$.

---

*How do you think about the elements of these fields*?

If you take any polynomial ring in however many variables, the field of fractions for that domain is just the formal "fractions of polynomials" with nonzero denominators. That's fairly easy to envision, no?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. So if $p(X) \in K[X]$ is irreducible it follows that it is minimal polynomial of $x \in K(x)$. Then $[K(x):K] = deg p = 2$. But how to show that it is irreducible? So intuitively it is because you already have quadratic polynomials and therefore $p$ has no root in $K$, but how to do this formal?

Comment: @guesterlein Your idea is already close to formal. A polynomial of degree 2 or 3 is reducible iff it has a root in the field. Then you already recognized that exactly $\pm x$ are roots of $X^2-x^2$ in $K(x)$ (There can't be any more roots!) But neither $x$ nor $-x$ are in $K$, so the polynomial has no roots in $K$.

Comment: I tried, see my edits above. How to fill the missing parts?

Comment: @guesterlein I think you're overthinking it. Isn't it clear that $K(x)=F_2(x,y^2)$ and that $K(x,y)=F_2(x,y^2,y)=F_2(x,y)$ as sets?

Comment: @guesterlein They can always be read as "smallest field containing this field and these other items." That makes it a little easier to think about.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Show that $1,x,y,xy$ is a basis of $L$ over $K$.

Or easier, you can prove that $[L:J]=[J:K]=2$ where $J=\mathbb{F}_2(x,y^2)$.